# Is there documentation to Demandware API for the integration with Salesforce?

Tags: integration, e-commerce, demandware

Please provide some links to the documentation and examples for the Salesforce Commerce Cloud Demandware API which can be used to integrate with Salesforce? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to create an account in the [XChange Community for Commerce Cloud](https://xchange.demandware.com/community/education). Once you have that, here's the link to the [Commerce Cloud Digital online documentation](https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC2/index.jsp).

Comment: I clicked the first link and it took me to the login page, where I didn't find a way to create an account. Both of the links took me to the login page only. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: All I could find is [this KA](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240130&type=1). I will ask my internal contacts and get back to you. The links I provided came from the Commerce Cloud Developer Certification Study Guide.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev , kindly let me know if there is an update in this. thanks

Comment: I've been given the name of a contact in the Commerce Cloud Team. I sent them an email on the subject this morning. Stay tuned.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev hope you had a great weekend. just checking for any update on this. thanks

Comment: This is all I have so far: "We are still working on the plan to get our Commerce Cloud content (virtually all of it) migrated to Salesforce systems. Some of this content is expected to be made widely available soon but I don't have the latest dates. Let me check with the owners of these 2 doc areas and confirm those dates - I'll get back to you asap." Will post when I hear more.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev just checking here if there is an update from your side on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now there is no need to have Xchange account to access the documentation it is open source now here is the link
[Salesforce Commerce Cloud](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp)